# How to create a linear graph with an indicator on it?

Tags: android, graph

Hi guys I want to know is it possible to create a line graph with a start point and end point and an indicator on it something like this;

```
                                 ||
                                 ||
                                 \/       C
A________________________________ |_______|___________________________________________B
```

And I want the "arrow" (in this case) to be moved by a given number (+ or -). If we say that point A = -100 and point B is + 100 and point C is 0 I want if I give the number 4 to the arrow the arrow to be placed at the position of number four on the line. What is the best way and most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Dead simple to do that by just extending ImageView, with a constructor as shown so you can add it to XML layouts (you do this in the form `yourpackagename.com.yourCustomImageViewClassName`):

```
public class LineGraph extends ImageView {


public LineGraph(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super(context, attrs);

    context = this.context;


} ...
```

From there, do you work as Canvas draws inside the classes `onDraw` method. You'll see many examples on SO. There are of course Canvas methods for drawing lines (graph), text (in any typeface), paths (the arrow), etc.